# can i pivot this entire query to return different results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query is returning exactly what i need but im trying to create a pivot table out of it as well.  I want to be able to SUM the column defined as SLAStatus in the CASE clause (dont know if thats even possible) as well as count the OrderID column as well as calculate(sum of SLAStatus column)/(Count of OrderID Column) to return a percentage of orders withing SLA. Been looking online everywhere but cant seem to figure this out

```
SELECT oi.OrderID, o.Address1 as StreetAddress, c.Name as County, o.State,                         p.Abbreviation, oi.OrderDate as Dateentered, 
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.DeliveredDate), 0) as DateCompleted, DATEADD(dd,                  DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) as EstimatedDeliveryDate, 

     CASE
WHEN oi.DeliveredDate <= oi.RequiredByDate THEN '1'
ELSE '0'
END AS SLAStatus,

cl.Name as Client, clb.Name as Client2,  v.ContactFirstName + ' ' + v.ContactLastName      as Appraiser

FROM OrderItems oi
JOIN Orders o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
JOIN Counties c on c.FIPS = o.FIPS
JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
JOIN Clients cl on cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
JOIN ClientBranches clb on clb.ClientID = cl.ClientID
JOIN Vendors v on v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
JOIN Milestones m on m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID


WHERE cl.Name not like '%TEST%'
and '2012-03-01' <=
        (select MAX(MilestoneDate)
            from OrderItemMilestones
            where OrderID = oi.OrderID
                and OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
                and MilestoneID in (100,130,140,150))

and '2012-04-10' >=
        (select MAX(MilestoneDate)
            from OrderItemMilestones
            where OrderID = oi.OrderID
                and OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
                and MilestoneID in (100,130,140,150))
```

Comment: It seems most of the query is unnecesary, then. Probably adding a small amount of sample data would help more than this. You shold also add your expected result in a tabular format.

Comment: can you expand on that a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a common table expression (CTE).  Just wrap your original query in a CTE then you can do the grouping you are looking for.

```
with originalCTE as
(
    SELECT oi.OrderID, o.Address1 as StreetAddress, c.Name as County, o.State,    
                         p.Abbreviation, oi.OrderDate as Dateentered, 
    DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.DeliveredDate), 0) as DateCompleted, DATEADD(dd, 
                     DATEDIFF(dd, 0, oi.RequiredByDate), 0) as EstimatedDeliveryDate, 

         CASE
    WHEN oi.DeliveredDate <= oi.RequiredByDate THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
    END AS SLAStatus,

    cl.Name as Client, clb.Name as Client2,  v.ContactFirstName + ' ' + v.ContactLastName      as Appraiser

    FROM OrderItems oi
    JOIN Orders o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
    JOIN Counties c on c.FIPS = o.FIPS
    JOIN Products p on p.ProductID = oi.ProductID
    JOIN Clients cl on cl.ClientID = o.ClientID
    JOIN ClientBranches clb on clb.ClientID = cl.ClientID
    JOIN Vendors v on v.VendorID = oi.VendorID
    JOIN Milestones m on m.MilestoneID = oi.LastMilestoneID


    WHERE cl.Name not like '%TEST%'
    and '2012-03-01' <=
            (select MAX(MilestoneDate)
                from OrderItemMilestones
                where OrderID = oi.OrderID
                    and OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
                    and MilestoneID in (100,130,140,150))

    and '2012-04-10' >=
            (select MAX(MilestoneDate)
                from OrderItemMilestones
                where OrderID = oi.OrderID
                    and OrderItemID = oi.OrderItemID
                    and MilestoneID in (100,130,140,150))

)
select sum(SLAStatus), sum(SLAStatus) / count(orderID)
from originalCTE;
```

If I understand correctly what you are looking for, then that is how I would do it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: i think i understand but ive only been working with SQL for about a month and dont know what CTE exactly means.  can you give me an example of one?

Comment: oh wait i get it now. Ill try this and return with results!

Comment: so i ran this exactly and it returns this

Comment: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: when clicking on that in sql management studio it returns me to the first line and highlites 'with originalCTE as

Comment: the column i want to get a sum of is one defined by me in the CASE clause, would that cause an issue?